# way to do Load testing on emulator for mobile app (without connecting to real device)

Tags: performance, android-studio, jmeter, load, mobile-application

Is there any way to run Load Testing for mobile application on Emulator without connecting to real device.

All i see over google is jmeter with mobile app on real device. but because i am connecting to remote desktop where my jmeter is installed this is not possible,

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference whether you use a real device or an emulator for recording the mobile application traffic, you can [specify the proxy for the emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#proxy) at the Extended Controls screen:

[image]

In case of recording HTTPS traffic you will need to install [JMeter's self-signed certificate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) onto the emulator and [allow trust for user added CAs in the network_security_config.xml](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri... i got the extended controls screen. I will surely try this and update the same.